# Equivalent to R's lines() function in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is it feasible to plot a line of predicted values in Python? In R, you can plot the line of predicted values using `lines(x$age, predict(result, data.frame(x$height, x$weight)))`. What I want to do is to plot such predicted values determined from the regression result, but also want to plot anything other than a simple, one-variable regression, which can be done in NumPy and matplotlib.

So for example, in the following code:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
result = smf.ols("res~height+weight+I((180-height^2))+I((60-weight)^3)", data=df).fit()
```

And I want to use the regression result from `smf.ols()`, which is a bit more complicated than the usual multiple regression (say, `res~height+weight`). So how can I determine the predicted values and plot those values?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to do with `matplotlib`?  `plot(x, y)` is I think the function you want, you just need to get the `x` and the `y` out of your data.